# WPF: affect border from style triggers

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I'm creating my own radiobuttons. I just want to change the graphics of it. They look as they want them to look but I'm unable to change the look of the `IsChecked` one ... This is what I have so far

```
<RadioButton x:Class="gMaterialWPF.MaterialRadioButton" [....]>
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="backPanel" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="10">

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

The problem is how to access the backPannel to change the color from the `<Trigger Property="IsChecked"` ??? I tried with TargetName but it cannot find the panel over there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried with `TargetName` but it cannot find the panel over there :(

You need to move the trigger to the `ControlTemplate` if you want to be able to reference the `Border` element using the `TargetName` property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Border x:Name="backPanel" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="10">

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="backPanel" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But since you have bound the `Background` property of the `Border` element to the `Background` property of the `RadioButton` using a `TemplateBinding` in your example, you don't really have to use a `TargetName`.

Comment: oh WoW :) How can I also change the color in the ContentPresenter text?? I need it to change to Black when the background is white ...

Comment: Set the Foreground property in a style setter. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `RadioButton.IsChecked` from `Style.Triggers` of `Border`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Border x:Name="backPanel" 
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"                            
BorderThickness="10">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">                                            
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}" Value="true">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}" Value="false">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>

        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```